# grep output format for spacing between filename and the matched line?

Tags: grep

How to make a space between filename and the matched line?
When you run "grep" for many files, it looks grep uses '-' or ':' (for number or string?) for delimiter between filename and the line. So depending on the line the delimiter can be connected with the first character or seperated with that. How can you make this be consistent for the consecutive work. In the consecutive work, I want to get the numbers on the same column using "awk". The details are like this.

The files can be written like this and the first column looks a 5-digit number to the right-aligned. And the last line of the loop can be different depending on the finish condition of the loop. And I am finding the last line of the loop using the next line of "...optimization bla bla".

case1 of a file

```
 9969 2020-11-23T14:20:09   6.7433e-02 1.0544e-03 - 2.1166e-03 C 1.2973e-01 - 1.4468e+00 C
...optimization unsuccessful.
```

case2 of another file

```
10072 2020-11-23T14:30:48   6.7384e-02 1.0569e-03 - 2.1148e-03 C 1.2968e-01 - 1.4539e+00 C
...optimization unsuccessful.
```

I want to get the number at $8, the 8-th value using "awk". Then I run

```
grep "optimization un" */log.txt -B 1
```

The output is

```
NN14/log.txt- 5015 2020-11-21T00:13:37   7.4772e-02 9.5215e-04 - 2.2506e-03 C 1.3664e-01 - 1.2459e+00 C
NN14/log.txt:...optimization unsuccessful. 392.1 min.
NN18/log.txt-10080 2020-11-23T22:41:12   6.5363e-02 9.1362e-04 - 2.4192e-03 C 1.2775e-01 - 1.3058e+00 C
NN18/log.txt:...optimization unsuccessful. 1517.2 min.
```

Then I want to get the number using

```
grep "optimization un" */log.txt -B 1 | awk '/T/ {print $8}'
```

Then the results become

```
C
1.2775e-01
```

So, I want to change "NN14/log.txt- 5015" and "NN18/log.txt-10080" into the same format with or without spacing. How can it be done? or is there any other way?
I tried using -T for tab but the delimiter attached to the line-side rather than filename-side so it is not effective.

Comment: It looks it is not possible to separate the delimiter and the line. But in my case, it would be possible to print $8 or $9 depending on the the number of line elements.

Comment: Since you aren't using the filename at all, you could do `grep -h` to exclude it, and then the intermediate data parses consistently for both lines beginning with space and not. Actually you don't need `grep` here, you can do the whole thing with (one) `awk` and then there is no intermediate data to _be_ inconsistent. But you apparently don't want that, since you exclude the possibilty of any better approach.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I am scanning all the directory with the same filename. Would you explain more exactly? Note that firstly it needs to find a last line in a sequential numbering in the middle of the file.

Comment: Comments are limited in length and formatting; see invalid 'answer' while/if it lasts.

Answer (score 1):

Meta: too much to explain in comment, but not an answer to the question asked.

I have no clue what you mean by "Note that firstly it needs to find a last line in a sequential numbering in the middle of the file.". The commands you show select the line before a line containing the string "optimization un" if it also contains the letter "T"; in the data you show this line contains some numbers and it may actually be that one or more of these numbers is sequential, but your selection has nothing to do with the number being sequential, or even being a number; your selection is based solely on the string and the letter.

You are grepping multiple files with `*/log.txt` so the *default* grep output starts each line with the filename and dash or colon. (And this has nothing to do with 'number or string'; it uses colon for the line *matching* the regexp, and dash for lines *before* or *after* the match that are included because of options `-B` (which you used) or `-A`.) But since neither colon or dash is whitespace, if the line sometimes begins with a space as yours do this affects the default field parsing by `awk` which uses whitespace. (`awk` field parsing *can* be changed, but for your data format I don't see any change that would work better.)

But you are then selecting in `awk` a line and field that does not ever depend on or include the filename, so if you *omit* the filename(s) it works. And `grep -h` omits the filenames. Try `grep -h -B1 "optimization un" */log.txt` (options like `-h -B1` are supposed to be before the regexp/pattern and filename(s), although GNU grep lets you put them after as an extension) and you should see data more like this:

```
 5015 2020-11-21T00:13:37   7.4772e-02 9.5215e-04 - 2.2506e-03 C 1.3664e-01 - 1.2459e+00 C
...optimization unsuccessful. 392.1 min.
10080 2020-11-23T22:41:12   6.5363e-02 9.1362e-04 - 2.4192e-03 C 1.2775e-01 - 1.3058e+00 C
...optimization unsuccessful. 1517.2 min.
```

(although IME you should also have `--` lines separating the chunks, which you didn't show) (but if present they will be skipped by the `awk` and don't matter).

If you now pipe that through your original `| awk '/T/{print $8}'` it should work.

But as I said you don't need `grep` (and its formatting) at all, just do:

```
awk '/optimization un/{print x} {x=$8}' */log.txt
```

Either of these should solve your problem, but neither answers the question you asked (to put a space between the filename and the matched line) and thus by Stack policy this is not a valid answer and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to separate the delimiter such as ':' or '-' from the line, there is a bypass to count the the number of fields in awk.

```
grep "optimization un" */amp-log.txt -B 1 | awk '{if(NF==11) {print $8} else if(NF==12) {print $9} }'
```

Then it gets:

```
1.3725e-01
1.3664e-01
1.2968e-01
1.2775e-01
```

regardless of "

```
NN12/log.txt- 5014 2020-11-20T23:34:02   7.5423e-02 8.5699e-04 - 2.2759e-03 C 1.3725e-01 - 1.1654e+00 C
NN16/amp-log.txt-10072 2020-11-23T14:30:48   6.7384e-02 1.0569e-03 - 2.1148e-03 C 1.2968e-01 - 1.4539e+00 C
```